# Does anyone have experience with wooden saddles?

Tags: product-rec, bike-fit, saddle

I've been looking online at [a wooden road saddle](https://citywood.ca/product/paris-saddle-complete/) and it looks pretty sweet but not sure how comfortable it's going to be... The description says it's made from maple wood and designed to flex, so it sounds like it should be a decent ride. But, it's wood.. so...

Anyone have experience with a saddle before?

Comment: It’s probably not unlike a pure carbon saddle. I’d be worried about the durability considering the high price.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Product recommendations are [off topic](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site. However, the core of your question was solid, so I have removed the portions asking for specific product recommendations. If you feel that I have changed the nature of your question, fell free to revert the edits.

Comment: And, like a pure carbon saddle, I would count on needing to wear padded shorts. It's unlikely that it will fit your behind perfectly, like a leather saddle would after wearing in.

Answer (score 2):

The description sounds like it is made up of multiple layers, boats built that way are very strong. Being thin, the wood will flex and return to its original shape – I wouldn't expect it to be like a Brooks saddle that molds itself to fit you over time. I think these saddles will be comfortable right out of the box. Or not. This article, [The Four and a Half Rules of Road Saddles](http://www.cervelo.com/en/engineering/ask-the-engineers/the-four-and-a-half-rules-of-road-saddles-.html), helped me sort out what to look for in a comfortable saddle.

Check out the maintenance the saddle requires. If the wood is not well sealed or if the sealing material wears out over time the saddle will start to fail (both from UV damage to the wood and from damage to the glue joints as the wood expands and contracts as its moisture level changes).

Those are beautiful. Looks like parts are available too. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing that can go one of two ways. Either it will work, or it won't.

The material for the seat does not always determine if it will be comfortable. I've seen a triple cushioned seat that would break your tailbone if you rode more than five miles on it; I've also seen a seat made of thick, hard resin-like material that felt like a pillow. Rather than the material of the seat, it all boils down to how the seat molds to your backside. If it is the right shape and the in the right position, you could have a section of 2x4 as a seat and it would probably be more comfortable than a cushioned seat that isn't the right shape/position.

Sorry to get a little off topic with that one. Anyways,as the first answer stated, I would be concerned about the integrity of the wood on the seat. Is the glue weather proof? Will the sealant fail due to the moisture from your rear? Will the wood flex? What if you chip the seat, will you get slivers?

I would suggest doing more research on the saddle, and most of all, see if you can find any product reviews. Good luck!